# How to extract contents by topic from a document?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, information-extraction, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to extract information from resumes. I tried the pdfminer for the text extraction. But I need to extract the contents from a resume with respect to its title.

For example:
I will be giving my educational details under a title **EDUCATIONAL BACKGROUND**, so I have to extract the content topic wise.

Is it possible to extract like that?

What will be the process behind that?

Is it possible to approach the problem in a segmentation manner.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a list of tools you can look into:

1. https://tika.apache.org/
2. https://jsoup.org/
3. https://poi.apache.org/

This was a neat read detailing the steps. The author was doing something similar to what you are trying.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-resume-parsing-tool-ae19c062e377

Answer (score 0):

pyresparser is useful for extracting information from resumes. I believe this should work in your case.

Check out the more details on the same here https://pypi.org/project/pyresparser/

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I have checked this also. Its good package but sometimes it fails to extract name etc but its good in extracting mob, email,skills etc